# Error in reading delimited text with decimals

Tags: r

I've stored data in a text file.
I'm using Windows 7 with IT settings and "." as decimal separator, ";" list separator.

Columns name are: label, x, y and f.

- Labels contains no data.
- x and y are coordinate (with decimals)
- f is ground elevation

Text file header:

```
 label      x           y           f
            2538359.78  4111150.05  1.73
            2538379.35  4111150.05  1.73
            2538398.91  4111150.05  1.72
            2538418.48  4111150.05  1.70
```

I import data in R with:

```
 f <- read.delim("corners.txt", sep="\t", header = TRUE, dec=".", stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```

I test data structure with:

```
 str(f)
```

R output is:

```
  'data.frame': 15390 obs. of  4 variables:
   $ label: logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
   $ x    : num  2538360 2538379 2538399 2538418 2538438 ...
   $ y    : num  4111150 4111150 4111150 4111150 4111150 ...
   $ f    : num  1.73 1.73 1.72 1.7 1.68 1.66 1.63 1.6 1.57 1.53 ...
```

Why both x and y value miss the decimal part?
How can I load data the right way?

I tried to read data with the Import Dataset function in Rstudio.
In the main window I choose "," as decimal separator (??) and in the preview window everything was as expected.

The command is:

```
 g <- read.delim("corners.txt", dec=",")
```

I test data structure with:

```
str(g)
```

I get this:

```
  'data.frame': 15390 obs. of  4 variables:
   $ label: logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
   $ x    : Factor w/ 90 levels "2538359.78","2538379.35",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
   $ y    : Factor w/ 171 levels "4109169.94","4109189.81",..: 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 ...
   $ f    : Factor w/ 396 levels "0.11","0.13",..: 161 161 160 158 156 154 151 148 145 141 ...
```

The data preserve the decimal for x and y columns but the import precess fails to read the f column.

How can I use the Factor to Number conversion to preserve decimals? Is it correct?

```
 h$x <- as.numeric(as.character(g$x))
```

The result is again with the missing decimal for the x column already processed:

```
 'data.frame':  15390 obs. of  4 variables:
  $ label: logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  $ x    : num  2538360 2538379 2538399 2538418 2538438 ...
  $ y    : Factor w/ 171 levels "4109169.94","4109189.81",..: 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 ...
  $ f    : Factor w/ 396 levels "0.11","0.13",..: 161 161 160 158 156 154 151 148 145 141 ...
```

I also look to:

```
 getOptions(digits)
```

and set it to 8 (instead of the default value 7).

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the values are there, just not printed. Try `as.character(f$x)` or something like `print(f$x, digits = 10)` to check.

Answer (score 3):

What you see in the console doesn't always 100% represent the true value. When printed to the console, values are formatted to look "pretty". This does have to do with `options(digits=)`. Setting it to 8 won't help with your values because you have more than 8 digits. Try 10 or more. Or try not worrying about it. Your data has been imported correctly.

Look at

```
f <- read.delim("corners.txt", sep="\t", header = TRUE, dec=".", stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
dput(head(f$x))
# c(2538359.78, 2538379.35, 2538398.91, 2538418.48)
```

The `dput()` will dump the "raw", unpretty data. You can see your decimal values are there. or try

```
options(digits=10)
head(f$x)
# [1] 2538359.78 2538379.35 2538398.91 2538418.48
```

Note that `str()` has it's own digits option as well

```
str(f, digits=10)

# 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ label: logi  NA NA NA NA
#  $ x    : num  2538359.78 2538379.35 2538398.91 2538418.48
#  $ y    : num  4111150.05 4111150.05 4111150.05 4111150.05
#  $ f    : num  1.73 1.73 1.72 1.7
```